# In Ruby, how to upload multiple files in single request using RESTClient

Tags: ruby

I have to upload multiple files as form request. I am using the Rest Client to post my request. I am able to upload single file but I am not sure how to add multiple files in a single request.

I searched/googled for such option and I am not finding any solution  that solves my problem.

Below is my code.

It has variable argument (*yamlfile)  which takes one or more files. I have to upload all the files together.

The issue now is , I am getting syntax error  when I add the loop to extract the file  within the payload. 
my assumption is now to form this outside the payload and include it inside the payload block but I am not sure how to do it. 
Can someone help me with that. 
( I have tried net/http/post/multipart library too and I don't find much documents around it)

```
def uploadRest(endpoint,archive_file_path,,yaml_file_path,*yamlfile)

  $arg_len=yamlfile.length

  request = RestClient::Request.new(
          :method => :post,
          :url => endpoint,
          :payload => {
            :multipart => true,
            :job_upload_archive => File.new(archive_file_path,'rb'),
            :job_upload_path => "/tmp",

           # Trying to add multiple file, but I get syntax error  
           yamlfile.each_with_index { |yaml, index|
              :job_upload_yaml_file+index => File.new("#{yaml_file_path}/#{pmml}")

              }

          })
  response=request.execute
  puts response.code

end
```

Comment: Can you show the backtrace you're getting?

Comment: The output of `.each_with_index` is the object it was called against. Also the key construction you are attempting will fail as you are trying to add a symbol and an integer (You should see `NoMethodError: undefined method '+' for :job_upload_yaml_file:Symbol`). If you built the hash separately and merged it in to your params, it may help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There were two issues with your question code:

1) Attempt to add a symbol to an integer

2) Attempt to insert contents of yamlfile direct into the hash (because that is what `yamlfile.each_with_index` *returns*, as opposed to how it calls your block. The return value from the block is not used)

Both of these code issues read as if you have gained experience in HAML or another templating language, and are using structures/ideas that would work in that?

There are lots of possble solutions in Ruby, but a simple approach to build up the hash in parts, as opposed to generate it in one go with clever hash-returning routines embedded. Try something like this:

```
payload_hash = {
  :multipart => true,
  :job_upload_archive => File.new(archive_file_path,'rb'),
  :job_upload_path => "/tmp",
}

# This does not use the return value from each_with_index, instead it relies
# on the block to make changes to the hash by adding new key/value pairs
yamlfile.each_with_index { |yaml, index|
  # This concatenates two strings, and then converts the combined
  # string into the symbol that you want
  file_key = ("job_upload_yaml_file"+index.to_s).to_sym
  payload_hash[file_key] = File.new("#{yaml_file_path}/#{yaml}")
}

request = RestClient::Request.new(
      :method => :post,
      :url => endpoint,
      :payload => payload_hash
)
```

For added code cleanliness, you could make the first two parts a separate method, and call it where it currently has `payload_hash`.

This should get you over current syntax hurdles. However, I have made no attempt to check whether this will allow you to upload multiple files via RESTClient.

Answer (score 1):

```
uploadRest(endpoint,archive_file_path,yaml_file_path,*yamlfile) 
@files=Array.new
yamlfile.each{ |yaml_file| 
          @files.push(File.new("#{yaml_file_path}/#{yaml_file}")) 
}
request = RestClient::Request.new(
      :method => :post, 
      :url => endpoint, 
      :payload => { :multipart => true, :job_upload_archive => File.new(archive_file_path,'rb'), 
:job_upload_path => "/tmp", :job_upload_yaml_file => @files }) 

    response=request.execute 
end
```

Comment: Thanks Anand. It worked my another solution was similar this .

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem and was able to get this to work by passing an array of arrays as a requests.

```
 file1 = File.new("#{yaml_file_path}/#{yaml_file1}", 'rb')
 file2 = File.new("#{yaml_file_path}/#{yaml_file}", 'rb')

request_body = [["files", file1], ["files", file2]]
RestClient.post url, request_body, request_headers
```

Answer (score -1):

Section1:

@params = {
        "FacialImage" => UploadIO.new(File.new('C:\temp\ATDD\Test\test\sachin.jpg'), "image/jpeg"),
        "Login" => UploadIO.new(File.new('C:\temp\ATDD\Test\test\login.txt'), "application/json")
   }

Comment: Can you provide more context?